# Is it great to make classes as functions, and declare parameters type with function types?

Tags: scala, testing, functional-programming

I'm working on a scala project, and my colleague who prefers functional style and proposes a way to organize code: Define classes as functions

Here is a sample:

```
class FetchFeed extends (String => List[Feed]) {
   def apply(url:String):List[Feed] = ???
}
```

When other class needs this class, it will be declared using the type `String => List[Feed]`

```
class MyWork(fetchFeed: String => List[Feed])
```

Then in some place, pass a `FetchFeed` to it:

```
val fetchFeed = new FetchFeed
val myWork = new MyWork(fetchFeed)
```

The pros is that we can easily mock the `FetchFeed` by passing a function:

```
val myWork = new MyWork(_ => List(new Feed))
```

The syntax is simple and easy to read.

But the cons is that, when I see the declaration of `MyWork`:

```
class MyWork(fetchFeed: String => List[Feed])
```

It's hard to see which class will be passed in, even the IDE can't help me. We need to search `extends (String => List[Feed])` in the codebase, or find the place to initialize the `new MyWork`.

And if there is another class which extends `String => List[Feed]` but which is never used in `MyWork`, it often will confuse me.

But if we declare it with the real type:

```
class MyWork(fetchFeed: FetchFeed)
```

It will be easier to jump to the declarations directly. But with this case, we can't pass functions directly, instead, we need to:

```
val fetchFeed = mock[FetchFeed]
fetchFeed.apply(any[String]) returns List(new Feed)

val myWork = new MyWork(fetchFeed)
```

I'm struggling with the two solutions. Is it a common pattern like this when write code in functional style?  Is there any open-source projects take this style that I can get some ideas from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style you described is not common partially because of the issues you mentioned. If your trying to achieve a functional style, you would be better off just using functions with type aliases.

```
// Alias the function type to a meaningful name
type FetchFeed = String => List[Feed]

// Declaring an implementation
val fetchFeed: FetchFeed = url => ...

// Nice type name to work with
class MyWork(fetchFeed: FetchFeed)

// Declaring a mock is still easy
new MyWork(_ => List(new Feed))
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution. It improved the readability a bit, but if the 4 lines of code are separated in 4 different files, and it's not easy to find what the implementation of `FetchFeed` is when you see `class MyWork(fetchFeed: FetchFeed)`. You can jump to the declaration of of `FetchFeed` easily, but not easy to find the actual implementation.

Comment: Could you recommend any open-source projects that you see them organize code like this?

Comment: The Effective Scala book (from Twitter) encourages that style (http://twitter.github.io/effectivescala/#Types%20and%20Generics-Type%20aliases ). I can't find any public examples of it at the moment.

Comment: type aliases don't guarantee static type safety; I would thus not use that style.

Answer (score 1):

Scala functions (`A => B`) can be seen as equivalent to Java interfaces defining a single `apply(a: A): B` method. So isn't the style you describe essentially the same as:

- The client depends upon an interface
- The interface is implemented by a hidden concrete subclass

And that's been completely standard, textbook Java style almost since Java was invented.

Back in the days when I wrote Java all day, I remember commonly using Eclipses Show Type Hierarchy shortcut to locate the implementing subclass.